# Get XY value from mathplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
x = [-5,-4.19,-3.54,-3.31,-2.56,-2.31,-1.66,-0.96,-0.22,0.62,1.21]
y = [0.01,0.01,0.03,0.04,0.07,0.09,0.16,0.28,0.45,0.65,0.77]
plt.scatter(x, y)

new = np.linspace(-6, 2)
line, = plt.plot(new, inter(new, x, y))

xdata = line.get_xdata()
ydata = line.get_ydata()
print("X-datas: {}\n Y-datas: {}".format(xdata, ydata))

plt.show()
```

X-datas: [-6.         -5.83673469 -5.67346939 -5.51020408 -5.34693878 -5.18367347
-5.02040816 -4.85714286 -4.69387755 -4.53061224 -4.36734694 -4.20408163
-4.04081633 -3.87755102 -3.71428571 -3.55102041 -3.3877551  -3.2244898
-3.06122449 -2.89795918 -2.73469388 -2.57142857 -2.40816327 -2.24489796
-2.08163265 -1.91836735 -1.75510204 -1.59183673 -1.42857143 -1.26530612
-1.10204082 -0.93877551 -0.7755102  -0.6122449  -0.44897959 -0.28571429
-0.12244898  0.04081633  0.20408163  0.36734694  0.53061224  0.69387755
0.85714286  1.02040816  1.18367347  1.34693878  1.51020408  1.67346939
1.83673469  2.        ]

Y-datas: [-0.01204394 -0.00302114  0.00328497  0.00731081  0.00949282  0.01026743
0.01007108  0.0093402   0.00851122  0.00802059  0.00830473  0.00980007
0.01270645  0.01709244  0.02276363  0.02951097  0.03669359  0.04295611
0.04814326  0.0535818   0.06028353  0.06926028  0.08176299  0.09625576
0.11210497  0.12895267  0.14776008  0.16925751  0.19376669  0.22132663
0.25163393  0.28441688  0.31953663  0.35641761  0.39468924  0.43398094
0.47401019  0.51426535  0.55412183  0.59301685  0.63038764  0.66578449
0.69938197  0.73201447  0.7646666   0.79832295  0.83396812  0.87258672
0.91516335  0.96268261]

[image: pic]

`inter` is function which is interpolates the datas, with that I get the outputed arrays.

How could I get a specific value from the fitted curve. Let's assume that X = -2.31 then I would like to get Y value from the fitted curve.

Comment: What is the `inter(new, x, y)` function you're calling?

Comment: inter is a function, which interpolate the datas, whit that I get the outputed arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the index of the closest point to `x = -2.31` using [`numpy.searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html).

```
n = np.searchsorted(xdata, -2.31)
y = ydata[n]
```

Remember that for this to work, you need `xdata` to be sorted, and the result will be slightly off because of the dx between two indices. The more points your data has, the more you reduce this inaccuracy to a point where it doesn't matter.

Comment: np.linspace(-6, 3, 200) with this I increased the accuracy, or I could use linear interpolation between the two closest point. Thanks for your answer